# How to delete data from the state to update a FlatList in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react native screen that fetches a user's tickets from the database, then renders them in a flat list. I have two questions (that I repeat at the end).

1. How do I pass {item.ticketID} to the deleteItem function?
2. How do I delete a given item from the State, so the list will automatically be updated?

Here is my class:

```
export default class MyEventsScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    tickets: [],
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/fullticket/?userID=4", {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          tickets: responseJson,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
            <FlatList
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              data={this.state.tickets}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.ticketID}
            />          
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the function I'm using to load each item of the FlatList:

```
function Item({ item }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.listItem}>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: item.eventID.eventImage1 }}
      />
      <View>
        <Text>{item.eventID.artistName}</Text>
        <Text>{item.eventID.eventName}</Text>
        <Text>{item.ticketID}</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => deleteItem()}
      >
        <Text>x</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And here is a function I'm using to delete a given ticket from the server:

```
function deleteItem(ticketID) {
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ticket/" + ticketID, {
    method: "DELETE",
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

I have **two questions**:

1. How do I pass {item.ticketID} to deleteItem()?
2. How do I delete a given item from the State, so the list will automatically be updated?

Any help is hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your first question**: How do I pass {item.ticketID} to deleteItem()?

You can pass `{item.ticketID}` to `deleteItem()` like this:

```
function Item({ item }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.listItem}>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: item.eventID.eventImage1 }}
      />
      <View>
        <Text>{item.eventID.artistName}</Text>
        <Text>{item.eventID.eventName}</Text>
        <Text>{item.ticketID}</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => deleteItem(item.ticketID)} // <=== This is how to pass the ticketId to your function deleteItem
      >
        <Text>x</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**For your second question**: How do I delete a given item from the State, so the list will automatically be updated?

You have to rename the function `deleteItem` to `handleDeleteItem` and move it up to your parent `MyEventsScreen` because it's responsible for managing the state and the last step you have to pass the function to your component `Item` via props:

Component MyEventsScreen:

```
 export default class MyEventsScreen extends Component {
      state = {
        tickets: [],
      };
    
      componentDidMount = () => {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/fullticket/?userID=4", {
          method: "GET",
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
              tickets: responseJson,
            });
          })
    
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };
    
      handleDeleteItem = (ticketID) => {
    
    
          fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ticket/" + ticketID, {
            method: "DELETE",
          }).then(res => {
    
            const {tickets} = this.state
            const index = tickets.findIndex((ticket) => ticket.ticketID === ticketID);
            const ticketsUpdated =  [...tickets.slice(0, index), ...tickets.slice(index + 1)];
            
            this.setState({tickets: ticketsUpdated })
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
        }
    
    
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
                <FlatList
                  style={{ flex: 1 }}
                  data={this.state.tickets}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} deleteItem={this.handleDeleteItem} />}   // <== This is how to pass the function handleDeleteItem to FlatList component
                  keyExtractor={(item) => item.ticketID}
                />          
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Component Item:

```
function Item({ item, deleteItem }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.listItem}>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: item.eventID.eventImage1 }}
      />
      <View>
        <Text>{item.eventID.artistIName}</Text>
        <Text>{item.eventID.eventName}</Text>
        <Text>{item.ticketID}</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => deleteItem(item.ticketID)}
      >
        <Text>x</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey! This is super helpful! I just seem to be having issue with the line of the FlatList component which says:
`deleteItem={handleDeleteItem}`

As soon as I include this line, I get an error saying it can't find the variable handleDeleteItem. What is the error here? I've tried adding "this." and brackets but can't seem to solve it.

Comment: You are right, there is an issue in the code. I added the props in FlatList component instead of Item component.

Comment: You are right, there is an issue in the code. I added the props deleteItem in FlatList component instead of Item component. I edited the answer.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you so much for that help! You are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your `deleteitem` function which you define in the parent component as a prop (like how you're passing `item`) from parent context into the child `Item` block. You can simply call in child as you have it and put `item.ticketId` that you're already displaying in Item. It will work just fine to pass it into parent context. So your touchable opacity will be:

```
onPress={() => deleteItem(item.ticketId)}
```

In the parent `deleteTicket` function you will have access to the state. Simply use whatever approach to filtering out the passes in `ticketId` you like.

```
 this.setState({
   tickets: this.state.tickets.filter(/*...*/)
 });
```

Also you may have to bind `deleteItem` state to `this` in parent constructor so it will be accessible when called from child. See this page for examples and explanation: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html.